# JavaScript を使い音声ファイルをトリミングしたい

Tags: javascript, audio

wavやmp3などを投稿できる音声ポートフォリオをつくっているものです。filereader.resultでファイルを表示して、その音声データをinput要素のrangeで始点を決め、そこから20秒だけ切り取り、データベースに保存したいと思ってます。

実現できそうな近いライブラリで [Blob.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) がありましたが、引数には時間ではなく、バイト指定でした。秒ごとのファイルサイズを計算してblob.sliceの引数にあてるのも有りですが、他に簡単にファイルをトリミングできるライブラリや、ヒントなど、ぜひお教えしてもらいたいです。
ご助力のほうお待ちしております。

Answer (score 0):

実際に試したわけではありませんが、英語版 SO の [How to cut a Audio mp3 Blob in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63583052) で紹介されている [simple-mp3-cutter](https://github.com/lubenard/simple-mp3-cutter) というライブラリが、時間指定で mp3 の切り取りを実現できそうです。

> #### Cut a mp3
>
> ```
> cutter.cut(blob, start, end, callback, bitrate);
> ```
>
> `blob` is the audio blob.
>
> `start` Start time in second.
>
> `end` End time in second.
>
> `callback` callback function (it is not possible to return data from async)
>
> `bitrate` is optionnal, default is 192

Comment: 返事が遅くなり申し訳ございません。早速試してみます。